# Test form with dynamic choice fields

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I created a form with a `TypedChoiceField`:

```
class EditProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, action, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if action == 'edit':
            project_year = kwargs['project_year']
            self.fields['year'].choices = [(project_year, project_year)]
        else:
            self.fields['year'].choices = [(now.year, now.year), (now.year + 1, now.year + 1)]

    year = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int)
    ...
```

This works perfectly fine when using it inside a view. Now I want to write tests for this form:

```
form_params = {
    'project_year': datetime.datetime.now().year,
}
form = EditProjectForm('new', form_params)
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

The test fails, because `is_valid()` returns `False`. This is because when calling `super.__init__()` in the `EditProjectForm`, the field `year` doesn't have its choices yet. So the validation for this field fails and an error is added to the error list inside the form.

Moving the `super` call after `self.fields['year'].choices` doesn't work either, because `self.fields` is only available after the `super.__init__()` call.

How can I add the choices dynamically and still be able to test this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your diagnosis of the problem is incorrect. Forms work exactly the same in tests as in views, and there's no reason it should try and validate it in `__init__` rather than waiting for you to call `is_valid()`. You should probably show the rest of the form and the test, and maybe the view too.

Comment: Actually, in this case it looks like you are passing data with the key `project_year`, but the form is just looking for `year`.

Comment: I'm completely confused. When I debug the test and just hit `F5`, it works. Running or using `F8` causes the test to fail??!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

The field `year` is a class variable, and is instantiated even before the tests `setUp` method and the forms `__init__` method was called. Since I haven't passed the required `choices` parameter for this field, the `error` was issued way before the form object was created.

I changed the behaviour so I change the type of the fields in the `__init__` method rather than using a class variable for that.

```
class EditProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, action, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if action == 'edit':
            project_year = kwargs['project_year']
            choices = [(project_year, project_year)]
        else:
            choices = [(now.year, now.year), (now.year + 1, now.year + 1)]
        self.fields['year'] = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, choices=choices)
```